# Uploading program to teensy not working

Tags: arduino, teensy

i got a brand new Teensy 3.2 with the blinking LED programm on it.

When I now tried to upload another programm on the teensy, Arduino says:

*Teensy did not respond to a USB-based request to automatically reboot.
Please press the PROGRAM MODE BUTTON on your Teensy to upload your sketch.*

The automatically starting window of Teensy, doesn't give me a chance to (for example) reboot the Teensy as well, so something of the connection seems to be wrong or something, but what...

Even if I mannualy press the pushbutton, it's still not possible to upload something. Any ideas why?

Comment: Possible reason is the cable being used is power only and doesn't have any data lines

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this problem twice. The first I tossed out the board. This time, when I power it, it runs the last program I burned on it, but when I try to program it again, the LED stops blinking and everything stops.
The claim that it might not be a data cable is not reasonable, because how can it stop the current program unless it was told to. I doubt very much that +5V can provide such commands.

I have tried different cables, different USB ports, rebooting my Linux box, reinstalling (twice), checking the pins on the Teensy and the cable... no clue.

It always boots up in the old app (I left the blinker running to indicate "liveness"). I had programmed a message to come out the hardware serial port. Could that have been the problem? Wait... Is there a way to set the baud rate on the USB? I wonder if that is the problem! --

```
Banner(void) {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial1.begin(115200);
};
```

The example had me programming the USB serial! I bet that is the problem! Better yet, does anyone know what the protocol is for talking to USB serial commander?

Answer (score 0):

Under Ubuntu 18.04 install this https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/49-teensy.rules file into `/etc/udev/rules.d`